# When can I drop the and on a list

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, lists

I saw this on the grammar section of a standardized test.

> The subjects they picked ranged from Dust Bowl refugees to civil rights activists, Olympic champions to labor organizers, land disputes to the growth of suburbia.

Why is there no "and" before "land"?

Comment: why do you think there should be one?

Comment: well because there needs to be an and at the end of a list

Answer (score 1):

> The subjects they picked ranged from Dust Bowl refugees to civil rights activists, Olympic champions to labor organizers, land disputes to the growth of suburbia.

The reason is that you would also have to include "from".

The subjects they picked ranged **from** Dust Bowl refugees to civil rights activists, **from** Olympic champions to labor organizers, **and from** land disputes to the growth of suburbia.

If you don't include "from" then you have to put "and" directly next to "land" and that destroys the grammatical structure of the list.